# Vectorizing cosine similarity computation in R

Tags: r, vectorization, trigonometry

I am computing cosine similarity between two items and have written the following code.

```
library('lsa')

df <-replicate(1, rnorm(500))

rownames(df) <- paste0("item", seq_len(nrow(df)))

colnames(df) <- paste0("value", seq_len(ncol(df)))



td = tempfile()
dir.create(td)


write( df[1], file=paste(td, "D1", sep="/"))
write( df[2], file=paste(td, "D2", sep="/"))


myMatrix = textmatrix(td, minWordLength=1)




res <- lsa::cosine(myMatrix[,1], myMatrix[,2])
```

How can I improve the code by lapply or apply method rather than using for loop between the rows?

Rather than writing df[1] and df[2] and so on, I would prefer iteration in a vectorized manner. I am new so please help me.

Please suggest the way forward. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `lsa::cosine(myMatrix)`?

Comment: Error in x[, i] : subscript out of bounds. getting this error

Comment: can you use `similarity` function from `recommenderlab` package? It is pretty fast and vectorized

Comment: Thanks for your time but your comment isn't helpful